# I'm using processing 2.2.1. I need to speed up a moving rect without making it too "choppy"

Tags: processing

I'm using processing 2.2.1. I have rw = rw - 2; and rect(x,y,rw,ry); in void draw; So the rect is evenly getting smaller. How do I speed this up (rw - 2) without changing it to 4. When I increase the number it speeds up but gets choppyer how do i speed it up while leaving the number smaller and smoother

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. for questions like these, it's customary to post code that works, rather than giving lines that you think are relevant without the program around it (although, make sure to not paste pages and pages of code: show a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) only)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: please add your actual (example) code to your post. This way we can see what it is you're doing. Also, use code formatting so the code stands out from the rest of your text. See the [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more info.

---

To speed up animation you can:

1. Increase the stepsize so bigger changes are made between frames (which you say you don't want).
2. Increase the framerate. If more frames are rendered in the same amount of time, the animation will be faster but still fluid as changes between frames are small.

By default, Processing tries to run at 60fps, which you can change using [frameRate()](https://processing.org/reference/frameRate_.html). Do keep in mind not all computers might be powerful enough to render at higher framerates. You can use the [frameRate](https://processing.org/reference/frameRate.html) variable to keep track of the current framerate to see if your computer can keep up.

Example:

```java
void setup(){
    frameRate(100); // set framerate to 100fps
}
void draw(){
    println(frameRate); // print the actual framerate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods you can use to accomplish this, but in general the "choppy" feeling is probably the fact you're scaling based on a number of frames rather than the physical world (physics!).

As a simple example try scaling based on time elapsed with a higher frame rate rather than relying on the frame rate be your scalar:

```
   int start;
    void setup(){
      size(400, 400, P3D);
      start = millis();
      frameRate(12);
      smooth();
    }
    int rW = 200;
    int rH = 200;

    void draw(){
      background(0);
      stroke(255, 0, 0);
      fill(255);
      rect(50, 50, rW, rH);
      int current = millis();
      float scalar = (current - start) * 0.1f;//arbitrary scalar
      rW -= scalar;
      rH -= scalar;
      start = current;
      println(scalar);
    }
```

You might want to look into Verlet integration and some physical models. Toxiclibs is a decent API that might give you some of what you're after. The key point here is that you can adjust the frame rate and your model will be in roughly the same place after time has passed. This gives a much more believable scaling rather than depending on the frame rate.

However, if the frame rate is consistent (it isn't always) then you can simply scale per loop. In my experience 60fps is running really smooth. Keep in mind film is 24 frames per second with some notable exceptions recently moving to use 48.

Comment: As a side note: yes, please post your code, it makes this much faster.